# video in list view: Scrolling getting black mark accored,when video is playing.

Tags: java, android

List view scrolling getting black mark problem when video is playing.

How to avoid block marks, when video is playing?

Comment: put the video view into any layout or create the video view in dynamic the problem was solved.